# Quando eu realizo um SELECT ele retorna vários registros duplicados

Tags: mysql, sql

Quando eu realizo um SELECT ele retorna vários registros da tabela postagens com mesmo id;

Eu tentei usar o DISTINCT para não retornar esses registros mas mesmo assim esta retornando registro duplicados.

[image: Imagem dos registros do retorno do select]

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tag_post 
INNER JOIN tag ON tag.id_tag = tag_post.id_tag 
WHERE tag.nome_tag LIKE '%quimica%';
```

Comment: Mas existem dois registros com o mesmo `id_postagem` com `nome_tag` diferentes. São duas coisas diferentes. Se vc quer apenas um, qual deles?

Comment: Tá meio confusa sua pergunta. Qual é o resultado que você gostaria de obter? Pois com o inner join você obtém os dados relacionados das duas tabelas. Nesse caso, pelo que entendi, está pegando todas as tags dos posts.

Comment: No que você postou não existem linhas totalmente duplicadas. Explique melhor que tipo de "duplicidade" você deseja evitar.

Comment: Teria de mandar exemplos das tabelas também, não só da view. E uma dica: geralmente quem usa DISTINCT já está fazendo algo errado, DISTINCT é um band-aid e quase sempre tem um jeito melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Ola

Experimenta fazer assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag_post.id_postagem, tag_post.*, tag.nome_tag FROM tag_post 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON tag.id_tag = tag_post.id_tag 
WHERE tag.nome_tag LIKE '%quimica%';
```

Ou assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag_post.*, tag.nome_tag FROM tag_post 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON tag.id_tag = tag_post.id_tag 
WHERE tag.nome_tag LIKE '%quimica%';
```

Comment: Meu problema não era aparecer id_tag repetido, e sim ter 2 registros com id_postagem igual

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi meu problema, meu professor me lembrou que como eu estava pegando *, os registros retornados eram diferentes por conta da coluna nome_tag, então o distinct não funcionaria, para resolver era só não pegar a coluna nome_tag. Como para o que eu precisava só precisava do postagem.id_postagem, ele só retorna registros de id único.

```
SELECT DISTINCT postagem.id_postagem FROM postagem
INNER JOIN tag_post on postagem.id_postagem = tag_post.id_postagem
INNER JOIN tag ON tag.id_tag = tag_post.id_tag 
WHERE tag.nome_tag LIKE '%quimica%';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e sem o DISTINCT

```
SELECT postagem.id_postagem FROM postagem
INNER JOIN tag_post on postagem.id_postagem = tag_post.id_postagem
INNER JOIN tag ON tag.id_tag = tag_post.id_tag 
WHERE tag.nome_tag LIKE '%quimica%';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]